# Android Studio: Unable to resolve Symbol 'requestLocationUpdates'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Working with a basic GPS code and I am running into an issue with the new Android Studio - I mean its preview software so far it has been reliable enough to be used full time. So here is the code giving me the issue:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WhereAmI extends Activity implements LocationListener{

TextView lat, lon, alt, status;
Context myContext = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whereami);
    lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latTxt);
    lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lonTxt);
    alt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.altTxt);
    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gpsStatus);
}

/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
LocationManager LM = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
//Gather GPS data at a certain time interval.
LM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1f, myContext);
//Check to see if GPS is on
boolean isGPS = LM
        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

//If its off, request to turn it on.
if (isGPS == false)
{
    //Enable GPS pop-up notification.
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);

    // set title
    adb.setTitle("Enable GPS?");

    // set dialog message
    adb.setMessage("Enable GPS to get full function from the app.");
    adb.setCancelable(false);

    //Yes Button
    adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                    0);
        }
    });

    //No Button
    adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // create GPS Alert [Pop-up]
    AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
else
{
    //Added this so when the app gets refreshed it will show the true GPS info status.
    status.setText("GPS Status: Enabled");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
    lon.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
    alt.setText("Altitude: " + location.getAltitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    status.setText("GPS Status: Enabled");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
}
```

For some reason it keeps coming up that it cant resolve the symbol for requestLocationUpdates.

Anyone else run into this or know a solution?

Comment: What kind of object is `myContext` ? Is it a `Context` ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Yes myContext translates to 'Context myContext = this;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `requestLocationUpdates()` function which takes `Context` as input. Following are the allowed parameters for [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) function:

```
requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)
requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent)
```

See [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) page as well. Hope this helps.

**Update**

Shift the following code inside `oncreate()`:

```
/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
LocationManager LM = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
//Gather GPS data at a certain time interval.
LM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1f, myContext);
//Check to see if GPS is on
boolean isGPS = LM
        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

//If its off, request to turn it on.
if (isGPS == false)
{
    //Enable GPS pop-up notification.
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);

    // set title
    adb.setTitle("Enable GPS?");

    // set dialog message
    adb.setMessage("Enable GPS to get full function from the app.");
    adb.setCancelable(false);

    //Yes Button
    adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                    0);
        }
    });

    //No Button
    adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // create GPS Alert [Pop-up]
    AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
else
{
    //Added this so when the app gets refreshed it will show the true GPS info status.
    status.setText("GPS Status: Enabled");
}
```

Comment: I did some changes and its still saying after setting up the proper values that its not being resolved.

Comment: Is it only this function for its giving the error? Try rebuild the project( from Build menu)

Comment: There are apparently a few issues in the file. This however is the primary one.

Comment: Can you post the code please. It might be because of some wrong import statements or others. Even one error is there, the project won't be built.

Comment: See my edit. Shift that peice of code inside onCreate(). That peice of code should run as soon as you start the activity. So it goes inside onCreate() function.